# How to find object only on parent page but excluding the ones under iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Let's say there are `<input>` array on the parent frame

```
<input type="text" name="address" id="address1" />
<input type="text" name="address" id="address2" />
<input type="text" name="address" id="address3" />
<input type="text" name="address" id="address4" />
<input type="text" name="address" id="address5" />
```

and there a iframe include another input array with the same name/id

```
<iframe>
    <input type="text" name="address" id="frmaddress1" />
    <input type="text" name="address" id="frmaddress2" />
    <input type="text" name="address" id="frmaddress3" />
    <input type="text" name="address" id="frmaddress4" />
    <input type="text" name="address" id="frmaddress5" />
    <input type="text" name="address" id="frmaddress6" />
</iframe>
```

However on main frame, when running jquery

```
$('input[name="address"]').each(function(key, value) {
    .....
});
```

it looks like all inputs including those under iframe are contained in the iteration.

So is there any solution could simple exclude those inputs under iframe? ( rename is not a option please :) )

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to have multiple elements with same Id. With that being said you could try something like this:

$('input[name="address"]:not(iframe)').each(function(key, value) {
    .....
});

Comment: @jasonwarford Thanks, like the idea, please make it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$('input[name="address"]:not(iframe)').each(function(key, value) 
{ 
    ..... 
});
```